# Vertically aligning flex 1 content

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a list where one of the items breaks onto two lines.

I need to keep all `<li>` elements the same height, but also center align them, which I can't seem to do ([code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Davidx000000/pen/Zazdga)):

```css
#test ul{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
#test li{
  flex: 1;
  width:33.333333%;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Two line Text</a><br/>
      <a href="">Two line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do what I'm trying to without using any hacky paddings, margins, or heights on the "One line Text" elements? If I use the suggested `align-items: center` on the `ul`, then the borders no longer look correct, as the element is no longer full height.

Comment: So you know, Stack Overflow has this neat feature called "snippets" -- basically, you can embed something a lot like codepen into your question itself. You don't need to link to an offsite thing that may or may not break everntually.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this works, but if it does I'll make it an answer. Can you possibly set the top/bottom borders (or left/right, depending on which direction your UL goes) in the `<li>`, and have the others on the `<ul>`? This should keep the borders aligned, while letting you have borders between them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the HTML structure a little bit & apply `align-items: stretch` to `ul`.

```
#test ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

And inside `li` create a `.inner` div and give it `display: flex` with `align-items: center`.

```
#test li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
#test ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#test li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#test li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

#test li .inner {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="inner">
        <a href="">Two line Text</a><br/>
        <a href="">Two line Text</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="inner">
        <a href="">One line Text</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="inner">
        <a href="">One line Text</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @David There is no need to change the markup at all, check my answer

Comment: @SauravRastogi User with less rep. than 15 can't upvote

Comment: @LGSon It may be possible that inside `li` there might be some other content as well. So `flex-direction: column` will always treat each and every child as a separate entity & will give less flexibility to the layout.

Comment: @SauravRastogi Well, there is a lot of _might be_ that can break any solution suggested, so why stop with just one extra element?

Answer (score 1):

`align-items` defaults to `stretch`, which make the `li` fill the height of the `ul`.

Change it to `center`, by adding `align-items: center;` to the `#test ul` rule, will align them vertically centered (this will make the `li` collapse to their content though)

```css
#test ul {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;               /*  added  */
  border:1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
#test li {
  flex: 1;
  width:33.333333%;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Two line Text</a><br/>
      <a href="">Two line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Or make the `li` a flex container and vertical align the `a` using `justify-content: center`, which btw defaults to `flex-start`.

Why the use of *column direction* and `justify-content`, because there is 2 items and you most likely want to stack them on top of each other.

```css
#test ul{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
#test li{
  flex: 1;
  width:33.333333%;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;

  display:flex;                      /*  added  */
  flex-direction: column;            /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;           /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Two line Text</a>
      <a href="">Two line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

If there is only 1 item with two lines of text, we can use the default *row* direction and `align-items`

```css
#test ul{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
#test li{
  flex: 1;
  width:33.333333%;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;

  display:flex;                      /*  added  */
  align-items: center;               /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Two line Text<br>Two line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">One line Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```